# pass laser scan to move_base

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

I am calling [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base?distro=hydro) to navigate my robot, by calling "rosrun move_base move_base _global_costmap/global_frame:=world".

[move_base Diagram](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=overview_tf.png)

But I could not find the parameter to define the laser_scan input topic and odometry topic. How do I pass these two parameters? I scan thru move_base.cpp, but cannot find any clue.

all comment appreciated!
thanks

Ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172884/pass-laser-scan-to-move_base/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2014-06-11**:
hi, i only have done this in groovy, but take a look at http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d#costmap_2d.2BAC8-flat.Parameters, you can pass the laser scan topic as a observation_source to the costmap, which move_base is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would heartily recommend using a launch file to set the parameters for move_base. There are many parameters, and trying to do it all via the command line will be too complicated. I would start with the tutorials listed here: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0